# javascript + Selenium WebDriver cannot load list of followers in instgram

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I am learning JavaScript,node.js and Selenium Web Driver.
As part of my education process I am developing simple bot for Instagram.
To emulate browser I use Chrome web driver. 
Faced problem when trying to get list of followers and amount of followers for the account:

This code opens instagram page, enters credentials, goes to some account and opens followers for this account.
Data like username and password I take from the settings.json.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
by = webdriver.By,
Promise = require('promise'),
settings = require('./settings.json');

var browser = new webdriver
    .Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();

browser.manage().window().setSize(1024, 700);
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/');
browser.sleep(settings.sleep_delay);
browser.findElement(by.name('username')).sendKeys(settings.instagram_account_username);
browser.findElement(by.name('password')).sendKeys(settings.instagram_account_password);
browser.findElement(by.xpath('//button')).click();
browser.sleep(settings.sleep_delay);

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/SomeAccountHere/');
browser.sleep(settings.sleep_delay);
browser.findElement(by.partialLinkText('followers')).click();
```

This part should open all followers, but not working:

```
var FollowersAll = browser.findElement(by.className('_4zhc5 notranslate _j7lfh'));
```

Tried also by xpath:

```
var FollowersAll = browser.findElement(by.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a'));
```

When I run in the browser's console:

```
var i = document.getElementsByClassName('_4zhc5 notranslate _j7lfh');
```

it is working fine.

I run code in debug mode (use WebStorm) and it shows in each case that variable "FollowersAll" is undfined.
The same happens when I try to check amount of followers for the account.

Thanks in advance.

[example of the selected element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq9Xd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In DOM, class names may be used multiple time. In this case, findElement by className wont work.

Xpath should be Relative and should not be Absolute.

Try Xpath with unique HTML Attribute. For example:
1. //div[@id/text()='value']

In chrome browser, open Developer Tools(press F12). If you framed an Xpath, just press Ctrl+F and paste that Xpath. If it states 1 of 1, then you can surely use that Xpath.

If it states 1 of many, then you need to dig deeper to take exact Xpath.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried to get xpath using different tools (e.g. using Chrome and using FireBug in Firefox), but result is always the same. Tried to get item by css - also no luck. Probably someone could tell me what I am doing wrong, or show how I can get item which shows amount of followers for account in Instagram.

Comment: can u attach the screenshot of dev tools with element highlighted ?

Comment: Added at the end of my question (example of the selected element).

Comment: Try with below xpath "//a[contains(text(),'followers')]//span"

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately did not help.